# How to change x86 opcode from compiled code

Tags: delphi, x86, reverse-engineering

Below is block of the code of an app I am reversing.
Please forgive me I new to world of reversing but I figured out that something is happening here and I thought I must change `je` to `jmp` but I am not sure if it's correct.

```
_unit34::TApplication.Run

     Push ebp  
     ebp,esp  
     ecx  
     Push ebx  
     Push esi  
     Push edi  
     Mov  dword ptr [ebp-4],eax  
     Mov. Eax,dword ptr [ebp-4]  
     Mov  byte ptr [eax+0AD],1  
     XOR  edx,edx  
     Push  ebp  
     Push. 4E2B09  
     Push  dword ptr fs:[edx]  
     Mov   dword ptr fs:[edx],esp  
     Mov   Eax,4D6574; DoneApplication  
     Call    AddExitProc
     Mov  eax, dword ptr [ebp-4]
     Mov  eax, dword ptr [ebp+44]
     Test  eax,eax
     Je    004E2AF1
```

Can someone explain a bit of what's happening there?
And how can I change `je` to `jmp` using Interactive Delphi reconstructor?

Comment: First of all, your disassembly is broken. I don't know if that's because of your disassembler, or because you typed it in here rather than copy-pasting. Secondly, all the x86 instructions are described in [Intel's manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html). You can find out what the code does by looking up the various instructions in the manual.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You are proposing to avoid entering the message loop? Of course, if you want to change JMP to JE, just do so. And don't bother reading `FMainForm` and testing it against `nil`. But why would you do so? As for "Interactive Delphi reconstructor", what is that? Presumably it's a tool. Did you read its documentation?

Comment: A quick Google search reveals "Interactive Delphi Reconstructor" as some kind of de-compiler. All sounds rather suspect to me.

Comment: ISTM that the code of `TApplication.Run` (in this case, the FMX version) can't be too much of a secret and does not really require a reversing tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone explain a bit of what's happening there?

```
 Push ebp  
 mov ebp,esp
```

Sets up a stack frame.

```
 ??? ecx  
 Push ebx  
 Push esi  
 Push edi
```

Save non-volatile registers

```
 Mov  dword ptr [ebp-4],eax
```

Save the Self pointer

```
 Mov. Eax,dword ptr [ebp-4]
```

Unfortunate stack trashing :-(

```
 Mov  byte ptr [eax+0AD],1
```

`Self.SomeBoolean:= true`

```
 XOR  edx,edx  
 Push  ebp  
 Push. 4E2B09  
 Push  dword ptr fs:[edx]  
 Mov   dword ptr fs:[edx],esp
```

`try`

```
 Mov   Eax,4D6574; DoneApplication  
 Call    AddExitProc
 Mov  eax, dword ptr [ebp-4]
```

Set the exit proc for the application

```
 Mov  eax, dword ptr [ebp+44]
```

`SomeObject:= somevar`

```
 Test  eax,eax
 Je    004E2AF1
```

`If (Assigned(SomeObject)) then .....`

> And how can I change je to jmp using Interactive Delphi reconstructor?

That particular change should make no sense here, because it would invoke an exception. The `je` is invoked when the object is nil. This is the error condition. You will change the program to always crash with an error.

However if you absolutly must do it, just change the opcode from $74 to $EB (for a byte offset jump) or from $0F84 to $90E9 (for a long jump).
I'd use a hex editor.

None of these changes will have a happy outcome unless you know exactly what you're doing.

**Where to start**
Get expertise in Delphi coding and view a lot of CPU output.
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to see what code Delphi produces.
This will take a number of months to years to master however.

**About reversing**
If you want to get into reversing [IDA pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) is a much better tool.
It has a freeware edition you can start with.

Comment: That analysis is not quite right. This is TApplication.Run. Unconditional jump is fine. That just bails out of the main message loop. And then the app terminates.

Comment: So you argue that the change will result in the normal code being executed with a nil ref. But it's the other way around. The normal code is always skipped, even with an assigned ref.

Comment: Okay guys, I am back again I have digging around till with same program and I found CFF Explorer's Hex Editor is easy to use but only one problem and I need help from Professionals.    I came across this (Function.Number:12..Number of components.F or This.function:1..Component.name:_27..number.of.actions:0..actionID:0..Param1:Please.activate.the.software.first!..) In the ASCII tab. Somebody seen this before?

Comment: @alexio, this is not a warez site. So don't expect cracking advice.